# Importing designs from Inkscape to android studio

Tags: xml, android-studio

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnzCE.png)
I have made this design in Inkscape and now I want to bring the purple background into Android Studio as a xml to set it as a background for a button

I have tried using Android Studios Vector asset tool but that doesnt work